# help getting products + their comments by followers with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, architecture

ok i have an product table. and a commment table. a user table and an social table.

**social**

```
SID AUID BUID
1   1    2 // user 1 follow 2
2   1    3 // user 1 follow 3
3   2    1
```

we can see that user id 1 is following user 2 and 3

**user**

```
   UID     NAME
   1       me
   2       imthenamefromuser2
   3       imthenamefromuser3
```

**product**

```
PID    UID    NAME           TIMECREATE
1      2      user2product   12-04-2011
2      3      user3product   12-03-2011
```

**comment** pcid = parent comment id

```
CID    UID    PID    COMMENT                  PCID
1      1      2      comment on product2      NULL
2      2      2      another comment on p2    NULL
3      3      2      someoneelse on p2        NULL
4      1      2      who are you?             3
5      3      2      im user 3 dude           4
6      1      1      a new post on p2         NULL
```

ok the question is

**how can we get the list of products their followers with their following comments ( max 20 comments )  ?**

heres what i have so far ( without the comments ) lets example the $uid is 1

```
function listFromFollower($uid){
    #here
    $data = $this->fetchAll("SELECT products.name AS product, users.name, products.pid, products.timecreate
    FROM products
    INNER JOIN users ON users.uid = products.uid 
    INNER JOIN social ON products.uid = social.buid
    WHERE social.auid = :uid", array( 'uid' => $uid));
    return $data;
}
```

it gets something like

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'product' => string 'user2product' (length=9)
      'name' => string 'imthenamefromuser2' (length=12)
      'pid' => string '1' (length=1)
      'timecreate' => string '2011-02-26 13:30:07' (length=19)
  1 => 
    array
      'product' => string 'user3product' (length=8)
      'name' => string 'imthenamefromuser3' (length=12)
      'pid' => string '2' (length=1)
      'timecreate' => string '2011-02-26 13:30:54' (length=19)
```

maybe it should be something like

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'product' => string 'user2product' (length=9)
      'name' => string 'imthenamefromuser2' (length=12)
      'pid' => string '1' (length=1)
      'timecreate' => string '2011-02-26 13:30:07' (length=19)
     0 =>
       array
         'name'     => string ''
         'comment'  => string ''
     1 =>
       array
         'name'     => string ''
         'comment'  => string ''
         0 =>
            array
             'name'     => string 'a threaded comment'
             'comment'  => string ''
     untill20 =>
       array
         'name'     => string ''
         'comment'  => string ''
  1 => 
    array
      'product' => string 'user3product' (length=8)
      'name' => string 'imthenamefromuser3' (length=12)
      'pid' => string '2' (length=1)
      'timecreate' => string '2011-02-26 13:30:54' (length=19)
```

Thanks!

Comment: I've asked sort of a similar question a while ago (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856682/sql-latest-photos-from-contacts-grouped-by-contact) and the consensus was that maybe it would be easier to intermix PHP with MySQL. As in one query can get so complicated that it's much cleaner to do multiple queries. I ended up following this road and I'm glad I did. YMMV.

Comment: yup that can do, the problem is im confused about the logic here... somehow now i can do something like listProductsCommentsFromFollower. im now trying to mix the two query so it can make sheathing like above.

Comment: The problem I see with multiple queries in this case is the nested comments. So my question is, why do you need all of the comments with each product at once? You have a page that lists all products, follower numbers AND every comment? Or do you, more realistically, have a page that lists all products, total followers, and total comments?

Comment: @kevin no we dont, we can limit them via sql with where, i suppose. im still on it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that doesn't really answer my question. I'm looking for your use case (what are you doing with this data?). Only then can I help you find the best method to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the result from the query to come out like you want. So there are two options. Run the query as you have and loop through each product to get their comments.

Or else get a large result that contains all the comments as well and them process to array to pull out the comments.

As Kevin Peno commented, is there any reason you need all this data? and not just the comment count? Because that would be a simple query with no processing.

Anyway here's a sample of how you could execute the 2nd option using a LEFT JOIN for comments:

```
function listFromFollower($uid){
    $rows = $this->fetchAll("
        SELECT products.name AS product, users.name, products.pid, 
            products.timecreate, commenters.name as commenter, comments.comment
        FROM products
        INNER JOIN users ON users.uid = products.uid 
        INNER JOIN social ON products.uid = social.buid
        LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.pid = product.pid
        INNER JOIN users AS commenters ON commenters.uid = comments.uid
        WHERE social.auid = :uid", array( 'uid' => $uid));

    $data = array();

    foreach($rows as $row) {
        // If we haven't added this product to data yet, add it.
        if (!isset($data[$row['pid']])) {
            $data[$row['pid']] = $row;
            // Tidy up the data, we don't want commenter and comment here
            unset($data[$row['pid']]['commenter']);
            unset($data[$row['pid']]['comment']);

            // Initialize an array for the comments
            $data[$row['pid']]['comments'] = array();
        }

        $data[$row['pid']]['comments'][] = array(
            'name' => $row['commenter'],
            'comment' => $row['comment']
        );
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Now you should have the same array as you had before, but now each element in the array with also have an array with the key comments that contains the comments.

Comment: This is the route I was probably going to go IF they needed all of the data...which just seems odd. Only issue I see is that you need to recursively add comments who are children of other comments to an array under the parent per his `maybe it should be something like` example.